# migration:rollback not rolling back with Laravel 4

Tags: migration, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to roll back my migrations in Laravel 4.

When I use php artisan migrate:rollback command, I get the following error:

```
MacBook-Pro:laravel-master ****************$ php artisan migrate:rollback
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'CreateFansTable' not found","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/crowdsets\/laravel-master\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Migrations\/Migrator.php","line":301}}
```

I am not sure why this is happening.  Running the migration works fine, but rolling back I am getting this error.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278322/laravel-4-how-to-delete-a-resource-with-its-files-and-records-from-the-project)